# Change a variable in a foreach loop in a view

Tags: variables, swiftui

during a loop to populate a list, I need to modify a variable that carries the total of the values ​​I have selected from a query. However, this is a small example.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var ore = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    @State private var conteggio = Int()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List{
                ForEach( 0..<ore.count,id:\.self){ora in
                    conteggio += ore[ora]
                    Text("ore: \(ore[ora])")
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

la variabile conteggio non è modificabile

Comment: You already had a list, why would you declare a computed property instead?

Comment: If you search for the specific error you are getting you’ll find several examples on how to overcome the issue

Comment: Also a `ForEach` isn't really a loop it is a `View`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of `ForEach` is not the right place to execute computations as it expects you to return a `View`. You should instead use a computed property that gives you the sum of the array:

```
private var conteggio: Int {
    return ore.reduce(0, +)
}
```